# Accessing variadic function arguments without stdarg

Tags: c, pointers, variadic-functions

Is there any way to access variadic arguments in a function using pointers? I tried doing something like

```
void test(int p, ...)
{
    int firstarg = *(&p - 1);
}
```

but that doesn't work.

How does va_start and va_arg access those arguments?

Comment: It's implementation-dependent.  Look at the source code for your implementation to find out.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700921/variable-number-of-arguments-without-stdarg-h-under-x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *portable* way to do that -- and no good reason to use any non-portable method (unless you're actually writing `<stdarg.h>` for a new system).

The macros defined in `<stdarg.h>` have to be implemented somehow. You could examine the contents of that header *for your implementation*, and possibly reproduce what they do -- but the result would probably not work on other systems.

If you're curious how `va_start` and `va_arg` are implemented on your system, you can take a program that uses them and run it through just the preprocessor phase.  If you're using gcc, then `gcc -E` will do this. But on some systems, they may be implemented in terms of compiler-specific extensions, so the results may not tell you much.

Curiosity is great, but in this particular case all you really *need* to know is that the macros defined in `<stdarg.h>` work as specified.

Comment: The macro was expanded to `__builtin_va_start(argptr, p);` -- not very enlightening. I am guessing that this means it is implemented as a compiler extension?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access variable function arguments without the `<stdarg.h>` header.

This part of the standard library falls under the "language support" category, i.e. it comprises library features that you need in order to take advantage of some of the language features.

Comment: Except how is stdarg implemented? Surely it must be possible to do something similar to how stdarg does it.

Comment: @user2612743: No. The implementation of the standard library is generally none of your business. You can look it up, but it won't be of any use, since it won't allow you to write any better code.