# variable number of arguments WITHOUT <stdarg.h> under x64

Tags: c++, abi

Variable number arguments can be done using `var_list` from `stdarg.h`, but how to achieve that without `stdarg.h` in 64-bit environment.

In 32-bit environment, function arguments are passed using stack from right to left, and are 4-byte aligned. So variable arguments can be accessed using address.

```
void func(int arg1, ...) {
    int arg2 = *(&arg1 + 1);
    int arg3 = *(&arg1 + 2);
}
```

In 64-bit environment (System V ABI), however, arguments are passed using registers. If registers cannot hold all registers, the extra are passed using stack.

So I want to know how can I access all arguments passed without `stdarg.h` under 64-bit environment. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm writing my custom kernel so I can't use standard C library.

`stdarg.h` defines `va_start`, `va_end` and `va_arg` as their builtin types, which seems to be a compiler-specific feature or extension:

```
...
#define va_start(ap, param) __builtin_va_start(ap, param)
#define va_end(ap)          __builtin_va_end(ap)
#define va_arg(ap, type)    __builtin_va_arg(ap, type)
...
```

Comment: Why don't you study your `stdarg.h` implementation to see what it does? And, why on earth are you trying to do this?  (I also suggest you mention your specific ABI earlier in your question, as people reading will think your assertions "arguments are passed usings stack..." wrong otherwise).

Comment: You may also be interested in [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) if you are only interested in compile-time variadic arguments.

Comment: Just use stdarg.h. That's what it's for.

Comment: I'm writing my custom kernel so I can't use standard C library.

Comment: Why is "compiler-specific" a problem? Do you want your code to be compatible with several different compilers? If yes, which ones?

Comment: Since the are compiler intrinsics, they are probably independent of the runtime library, so you can use them in kernel mode. Linux uses gcc, and it uses stdarg.h in kernel model.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently faced with this when implementing a toy version of the libc `syscall` function. You can always use assembly to do this if portability isn't a concern. Here's how I did it:

```
ssize_t syscall(size_t sysno, ...) {
  // The x86_64 calling convention uses rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 and r9 as args
  // The kernel interface uses rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8 and r9 for arg and rax for sysno

  asm ("mov %%rdi,%%rax;" // System call number (sysno)
       "mov %%rsi,%%rdi;" // first syscall arg and va_arg
       "mov %%rdx,%%rsi;" // second syscall arg and va_arg
       "mov %%rcx,%%rdx;" // third syscall arg and va_arg
       "mov %%r8,%%r10;"  // fourth syscall arg and va_arg
       "mov %%r9,%%r8;"   // fifth syscall arg and va_arg
       "syscall;"
       :
       :
       :

  register ssize_t ret asm("rax");
  return ret;
}
```

In my case, I just wrote the whole function in assembly, but you could do something less extreme such as:

```
register long arg1 asm("rdi");
register long arg2 asm("rsi");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function with enough arguments so there is at least one that is passed on stack:

```
void func(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6, int arg7 ...) {
    int64_t* stack = reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&arg7);
    int arg8 = (int)stack[1];
    int arg9 = (int)stack[2];
}
```

Note that the addresses on stack are incremented in steps of 8 (the "natural" type for accessing stack has `sizeof` equal to 8).